Could today's flash memory be used instead of RAM in 1980s 8 bit machines?
I wonder if this is possible and could be a retro-project? (Not something I would try myself, though)
The bandwidth of flash is surely faster than yesterday's 1980s RAM (?)
Why? One possible interesting outcome could be the non-volatile nature of Flash.  Imagine being able to pause a game or other activity, then be able to go straight back to that following a power on at a later time.
The CPU state would need to be stored, if that doesn't have flash memory. Or could an FPGA incorporate Flash memory.
An academic exercise without useful application maybe, but may give intellectual englightenment about what it means to save data, when there is no need, because memory is non-volatile.

There were plenty of options for non-volatile memory even in the retro era, e.g. EEPROM or just battery backed SRAM. So this could have been done at any time, given the will and the money.  Flash isn't fundamentally new in that regard; it's just cheaper and thus easier to have more of it.

Flash would need some extra circuitry to emulate RAM because you have to erase it by blocks in order to overwrite it. But sure, it can be done. And retro era computers are generally tolerant of any timing differences that would be introduced; just signal enough wait states.

Core memory based systems, especially minicomputers, were often able to be turned off and then resume from where they were when turned on again.

Furthermore, we wrote powerfail handlers - you get an interrupt when the power is on the way down, which gave you a few milliseconds to save volatile state (device registers, etc) to core, so you can resume when power comes back up.

@DaveTweed still has relevance today, offline first: where power and internet are intermittent e.g. large rural developing world continents.

@DaveTweed While retaining core, they still often needed manual interaction for restart.

@dave Some designs even hat special power fail states. For example the Siemens /360s had a P4 state activated in this case which provided its own register set (well only 4 of 16) so enough time to halt the IOC in a defined state and write state information to a dedicated core area, allowing (almost) seamless restart.

FRAM is probably the modern solution to this.

Every time I see one of these questions, I am reminded of a gamer who created a huge ramdrive on disk, copied all the game files to the ramdrive and executed it from there. I think this was in Windows 3.1 or 95 days. He said it improved game performance. I am dubious.

Bandwidth is meaningless for random access, you need to look at IOPS which is still in tens or hundreds of thousands for flash. RAM could achieve MHz rates already in the 1980s.

It's going to depend on the hardware. A system which uses main RAM for video (with access shared by video hardware, sometimes on alternate cycles) will have obvious problems. You need to be more precise.

@StuartF, but if Flash EPROM clearly can't remotely keep up with even the slowest 1980s random access byte writes (call it 0.5 MHz) as per all the answers below, surely there's no need to be more precise. It's not on some sort of a knife edge - Flash is far too slow to keep up with RAM byte writes by anything from that era.

No, Yes, But No, But Maybe, Also There's Better Stuff
It's memory, but not as straightforward as it seems, so let's try to go along the posibilities:
No
Conventional FLASH is a block device. Like a disk drive. Its optimized for (relatively) rare writes of large amounts of data at once, not bytewise operation. The issue is much the same as why hard disks do not make great RAM (*1)
Yes
Flash-based storage designs could be used as RAM with speeds acceptable for late 1970s CPUs (*2). Read speed is much better than a 70s CPU needs, while write may need some wait states, depending on FLASH type (*3).
But No
Except, most FLASH (*4), especially those available as discrete devices, are not made to allow write access with arbitrary values in byte-size chunks. They are value sensitive and based on block architecture for erase operations (*5,*6). As a result byte-wise write is only possible if a cell is 'empty' or the new value is 'compatible' (*7). Otherwise an erase operation is needed wich may need several milliseconds - that's thousands or even millions of cycles(*8) even for a slow 1970s CPU (*9).
Maybe more importantly, write and erase operations need multi-cycle commands (*10), thus no classic CPU can write on its own, without additional logic halting the CPU and inserting those commands.
Last but not least, Flash provides only a few hundred thousand to maybe a million writes. If used for heavy-duty RAM - think 6502 zero page - this may already be exceeded after a few minutes of operation. Not really durable.
But
Of course one could add some controller hiding the complex write handling of Flash. It would let read access through while hiding write handling (while halting the CPU) on its own. Given enough buffering and intelligent storage organization this could be done with no or minimal timing impact to a classic CPU (*11,*12,*13) - at least on average (*14). And while such a controller can as well average utilization and postpone death by writing a bit, it would not really result in a long lifetime (*15).
Of course the effort of such a controller would be extreme in 1970s technology terms. Such a controller might have to be more complex than a 1980 computer in total. Not a big deal today, but kinda uncool.
There's Better
Yes, Flash is what we think today first for changeable and durable memory, but there are several more, even older technologies, the most relevant for your case might be:
EEPROM
The oldest still in wide use is EEPROM. While classic EEPROM were really single byte writeable without much speed penalty, modern ones are in fact Flash-based. They include a controller somewhat like described before - except not optimized for write speed. The relevant difference to Flash is that the interface works like classic RAM, thus it needs only minimal additional logic to make it work with a classic CPU. Though, it's quite slow at ~2ms with each write.
MRAM
Magnetoresistive RAM was already developed back in the 1980s. In some way it works like classic core (*16). It was most of the time a rather obscure type with low quality and high current demand. Development only took off after 2000 when Infineon invested quite some effort for use with their embedded/automotive systems. Retention time is guaranteed for 20+ years. So at least as good as Flash.
Today a low-end Infineon/Cypress will be good for a 10 MHz 6502 or 20 MHz Z80, all with SRAM compatible access. Standard sizes are 8, 32 and 128 KiB.
FRAM
Ferreroelectric RAM might be even older, as it dates back to the 1950s. It works again like core (*17). Due to its destructive read, cycle times are notably slower than with MRAM: about half, so still good for even the fastest classic CPU. Retention time is even better than MRAM.
In fact, it was used with one of the most common classic systems, Sega's Mega Drive (Genesis). Well, not directly, but within the Sonic the Hedgehog 3 cartridge as game save.
And then there is:
NVSRAM
NVSRAM is a combination of SRAM and a non volatile storage in a single chip. Most interesting here are chips with combined bit cells of SRAM and a long term storage, usually Flash. During normal operation all read or write goes into the SRAM part. Only during power down the SRAM is written to long term storage. Having both types integrated in each bit cell allows to write the whole chip in a single operation, powered from an external capacitor.
Speeds are exactly like modern SRAM, so more than sufficient even for early 1990 32-bit systems. Size-wise they are usually a magnitude smaller than SRAM of the same time - again way past what an 8-bit system may handle.
Note, some RAM marketed as NVRAM are non-volatile not by storage structure but by an integrated battery system, which makes them battery-buffered (BBRAM) - maybe the most interesting category here:
Battery Buffered RAM
Yes, why not simply add a battery? Back when 8-bit CPUs were a thing, using SRAM with an added battery was the standard solution (*18). While back then batteries had to be large to cover the need of many chips, today it would be just one or two and at much lower power consumption (*19). A 256 KiB Chip with 9 µW standby can work from a single button cell for 10+ years.

Bottom line: There are way better ways than spending time to make Flash act as RAM.


The bandwidth of flash is surely faster than yesterday's 1980s RAM (?)

So is any other storage technology - including SRAM going down to less than 10 ns - that's good for a 50 MHz 6502 :))

One possible interesting outcome could be the non-volatile nature of Flash. Imagine being able to pause a game or other activity, then be able to go straight back to that following a power on at a later time.

Well, that doesn't need any special Flash-as-RAM setup - only an interrupt routine activated when hitting PAUSE and writing all RAM to regular FLASH. Likewise simply reading the last state from FLASH when restarting. Software will do.

The CPU state would need to be stored, if that doesn't have flash memory.

Which needs software anyway. Even if the RAM is fully non-volatile, the CPU isn't.
Nor are I/O circuits (video, etc.) and attached devices - all of that needs reinitialisation before the game can be resumed.

An academic exercise without useful application maybe, but may give intellectual englightenment about what it means to save data, when there is no need, because memory is non-volatile.

It's not about data but about the state of the system, of which RAM is only one part.

*1 - Well, very early machines operated with drums as RAM - but their operation was also in a range of a few kOps, so rather fitting.
*2 - Our beloved 1980s 8 bit computers were all powered by 1970s CPUs, like 8080, Z80, 6502, 6800, etc. Even 8086 and 68k are firmly founded in the previous decade.
*3 - Since it's only about write, this may or may not result in any real time slow down, depending on system design. Write time is, depending on device, somewhere between 4 and 100 µs.
*4 - There are some micro controllers with embedded Flash working in different structure.
*5 - That is, single bytes cannot be erased, only whole blocks at once - depending on chip type a block may be several hundred bytes to many kilobytes.
*6 - Some are based on a page write structure which means that only a whole page (e.g. 2 KiB) can be written at once.
*7 - Flash (NOR at least) holds an all one (x'FF') value when 'empty'. (Byte) write operations can only set bits to zero. So FF may be overwritten with any 8 bit value, but if the cell already has a non-FF value, only those bits still set can be cleared - so a '5' (x'35') can be overwritten with '4', '1', or '0', but not '3' or '2'.
*8 - Depending on device, erase may be anywhere from 1 ms to several seconds - usually longer for larger devices.
*9 - A millisecond equals 1000 cycles on a 1MHz 6502 or 4000 cycles on a 4 MHz Z80.
*10 - That is, writing of several consecutive bytes with command information.
*11 - For example, writes can be checked for being compatible to be performed without erase.
*12 - Not to mention write-back buffering for hidden write, maybe even delayed to catch multiple writes within a time frame. Here already a small cache can make a huge difference as 8-bit micros often manipulate the same few RAM cells over and over.
*13 - Likewise, Flash storage could be handled not as flat memory but a transaction log made as linked list. Updates would be added at the end, while reading follows the list. Since Flash is 5-10 times faster than what the CPU needs, that list hold 5-10 changes before an erase will be needed - unless a next level structure is used to postpone the system freeze (*13) even further.
*14 - There will be hiccups - quite notable ones when an erase has to be done. The system might freeze for seconds ... not really great when playing a shooter or editing RC.SE :))
*15 - Even if the algorithm would improve durability by 1000 times, making it go from 15 minutes to 15,000 minutes would still only give 250 hours, maybe a month of daily usage, before one has to solder a new FLASH.
*16 - Except rather than reading magnetic moment due to remagnetization, instead its state is read due to measuring resistances. Thus it does not need rewrite.
*17 - Even more than MRAM, as while detection is by charge (like Flash), read is destructive.
*18 - Already the Solid State Music's 8 KiB S100 board of 1977 offered that luxury.
*19 - Most modern RAM designs provide automatic low power modes. When not accessed they go down to very, very, very low current. Single digit µW numbers are standard for ultra low power.

I like your answer, but having all the footnotes at the bottom is cumbersome to say the least. I have to scroll down and back up several pages just to check out one footnote, and it takes me out of the flow of reading the text. There has to be a better solution for that :)

@marcelm Well, the whole reason of footnotes to improve reading by getting secondary information moved out of the way. I'm already infamous for way too long write ups :))

If you're using a battery and low-power SRAM, couldn't the CPU state also be preserved easily if the CPU has a static core (like 65C02)?

@Theodore Of course. Same would have to be done with all I/O chips and of course all connected devices, as their state is as well relevant for seamless restart. That's essentially letting the machine continue to run - and eat up the battery rather fast. The very reason why even modern systems that offer suspend states need software in addition to hardware.

@Raffzahn: you could add the footnotes at the end of each section

+1 and accepted answer, superset answer covers the other answers. I'm grateful to everyone who answers and have upvoted all answers.

Might want to add Optane to that list, it was used as non-volatile RAM in real computers (servers) this decade.  Sadly Intel discontinued it a few years ago, but you can still pick up modules second-hand.

@QwertyChouskie Well, it's not a generic list of non-volatile memory, but types that go well with classic CPUs and are available in household quantity.  PCM (aka Optane, aka X3D)  wasn't really available as direct RAAM replacement. They featured either complex bus protocols like modern DRAM, or FLASH like operations. The closest usable might have been Numonyx' (Intel spin off, now Micron) Omneo P8P PCM chips. They might have been fast enough, but would still need a controller to translate access protocol protocol. 'might have' as they are as well no longer available.

@Raffzahn a propos 4 AMD sold flash memory chips in the '90s that were extremely fast (20 and 30 ns) for 1 MiB (128KiB8) that were programmed in unusual way. You had to clear big sectors of 4KiB setting to all 1. You could then write byte wise but only transition from 1 to 0 was possible. Once a 0 was written it was permanent until cleared in a block of 4 KiB....

@Raffzahn ... contrary to the Atmel chips of the time were you always had to write/clear in blocks of 256 bytes. Programming always required the writing of at least 256 bytes. The Atmel chips were also slower (80 to 90 ns). I do not remember which was NOR flash or NAND flash. The AMD chips were very delicate to use but we required their speed for the Rockwell modem chipset which being 6502 based needed very fast memories.

@Raffzahn *10 The CPU can do the state machine sequence necessary to write to flash memory itself. We did it with our 80186 based controllers in the 90s all the time. It is extremely timing sensitive but did function even in our circuits that were not specifically designed for flash.

@PatrickSchlüter Random byte wise write the default way of working for most in system flash. Therefore it's what above assumes. Also, the question is not about using flash with 8 bit CPU, I do that all the time, but using it as RAM.

I am already thinking of SSD based search engines like WiSER. Of course current hardware probably isn't exactly suitable for this, but I wonder about the future.

No, because the game expects to access the memory as RAM, where any address can be arbitrarily read and written to replace current contents.
Or rather, no, unless many obstacles are solved, when it becomes a yes. So the method you suggest would be a difficult method, while better methods exist.
Flash memory does not support arbitrary rewrites. Usually, you can only program bits to logic zero, even one bit at a time, but clearing any bit back to high requires an erase, and as Flash memories work in large blocks, a whole block of memory would be needed to erase to contain all logic ones, and that would mean the contents of the whole block must be read and stored somewhere temporarily, in order to do the erase, and then the original block data needs to be programmed back, with the one changed bit you changed from zero to one.
And those blocks are large, and erase is a slow process, compared to a simple RAM write.
Flash memory cell also wear down from constant use - it includes erasing, writing, and reading too.
Also the CPU state would not be stored into external Flash memory, unless there is some program code to do that.
So rather than putting Flash memory in place of RAM, it would make more sense to just add Flash with some additional method the user can trigger a piece of code to be executed, that will erase the Flash, copy RAM contents to Flash, and then copy CPU state and also state of everything else such as sound chip and video chip etc to the Flash too, so that the next time someone turns the device on and does some action which stars executing the process of restoring the state, it can do so for every bit of the hardware.
And sometimes some control registers are write-only, so it will be impossible to read back the current state in order to store the current state into Flash.
At least unless you add an FPGA to the bus which can trap such writes and store them until the state saving code can fetch the data from FPGA.

Worth mentioning that there are non-volatile byte-addressable memories, like 3DXpoint, notably used in Intel's discontinued Optane products, including DIMMs that connect to the memory bus of Xeons - I wrote an answer on Superuser about Optane DC-PM DIMMs that can truly work as slower RAM vs. just NVMe SSDs still only working as block devices so at best fast swap space.

Flash devices take various amounts of time to do various things:

Read sequential bytes of memory

Switch to reading memory from a new address.

Write a moderately small chunk of memory into a blank portion of a block (some devices can write individual bytes, but many are limited to writing a 512-byte page or an associated 16-byte auxiliary storage area which is is blank before the write operation; once a page or auxiliary region has anything written to it, nothing more may be written until it is erased.

Erase a block containing hundreds or thousands of pages.


It's easier to increase the speed of #1 relative to #2, than to increase #2, writes will be massively slower than even random reads, and erase operations will generally be slower than that.
Even if a flash device can write dozens of millions of bytes per second, writing anything smaller than a 512-byte page in a manner that would facilitate fast retrieval would require reading 512 bytes into a buffer, patching the portions that should change, and then writing a new 512-byte page to a blank portion of the chip.
If one were to design a device which wrote to flash every address and data value that was accessed from a conventional RAM, such a device may be able to keep up with 8-bit CPU speeds, but a conventional RAM just as big as the original would be needed to satisfy read requests, since finding the value of any byte, using only information stored in flash, would require scanning through the entire list of accesses to find the last one that wrote to a particular address.

And now, for extra fun, each flash block can only be written to so many times before it is worn out.

@WayneConrad Not only written, but read too. See "Read Disturb".

@WayneConrad: True, but designing something that could work for even a second without a RAM backing store as big as what one was emulating would be problematic unless the goal was to emulate something that during use would be read-only (e.g. the Wirtable Control Store on the Amiga 1000), in which case some kinds of flash would be suitable.

@supercat That's the conclusion I reached also.  You'd be essentially have a bank of RAM that was backed up asynchronously to flash, and restored from it during boot.  It'd probably be much cheaper and far less dodgy to just add enough batteries to keep the RAM going for a "long time" when the device is powered off.

@WayneConrad: Or if you really want huge endurance without power, even if the battery can be removed, you could have a (super)capacitor to give time to copy DRAM to flash on power loss.  You probably don't need wear leveling if it's just a 1:1 full-RAM copy, since write cycles = power cycles.  But yeah battery-backed DRAM or SRAM is fewer components and less logic (including not needing an extra thing that accesses the memory bus.)

The data byte read speed of modern Flash EPROM is much higher than that of 1980's RAM.
However, Flash byte writes are much slower:

the block-at-a-time erase-then-write structure doesn't support single byte modifies
erase-write cycle is far slower than that RAM
the Flash write interface uses control and status registers, unlike the fast modeless pin-controlled RAM writes

For what you're describing, the RAM and the Flash EPROM may both be memory chips but that's about as far as the similarities go.

One might underline the last sentence.

@Raffzahn, such emphasis makes it read over-anguished/shouty, plain text is almost always better.

Well, IMHO it's the central point here,. I'd say it deserves being shout out like a headline.

@Raffzahn, it's there, nice and clear and unmissable. Adding emphasis is telling readers that they can't work out what's important and need it done for them. It can come across as between lecturing and patronising. Text should be written for the good of the reader, not because writer likes doing it. Readers aren't daft. Look at books, novels, datasheets, technical notes, emails etc. All use no/miniscule emphasis and communicate well. Keeping it short, simple and clear wherever possible, that's the goal - makes it easier to understand and remember. It's all around you.

I'm all with you, as all those arguments describe the very reason why highlighting by headline or underlining exists.  A somewhat long life of (often written) communication with people from all trades of life told me that structure is the most important part. This is exactly about writing for the good of the reader, supporting understanding.

One major difficulty using Flash as RAM in an 80's computer is the architecture of the RAM itself:
Many 80's systems, (the vast majority, if not all), used dynamic ram, typically 8 chips of one bit memory, or two chips of four bit memory for smaller memory footprints.[1]
Dynamic RAM is sufficiently different from static RAM that it would require a major redesign of the entire system to accommodate it.
========== Footnotes ==========

The Atari XE originally shipped with 16k of RAM organized as two 4 bit by 16k chips, but could be modified to use 8 64k by 1-bit DRAM.


Isn't it rather the other way around? Modern CPU assume DRAM, while classic 8-bit assume a static bus. Adding a static RAM to most 80s machines is straight forward - including the 8-bit Ataris.

I'm afraid that's not true.  The 8-bit machines I repaired, including the Commodore and Atari machines all used DRAM because it was both faster and cheaper.  SRAM back then was slow, small, and expensive.

Well, yes, they use DRAM as it was cheap in relation to size, but not necessarily faster. Most classic CPU (e.g. 8080, Z80, 6502, 6809) provide a static memory interface, thus all machines using DRAM added control logic to turn create a DRAM interface from that. Also, most machines I remember did not offer that DRAM interface for expansion buta variation of the plain CPU bus (e.g. PET, C64, Atari 8-bit, TRS-80, CoCo, BBC, Sinclair, Apple  II, etc.).
